# Codeigniter equivalent of Zend headscript

Tags: javascript, css, zend-framework, codeigniter

Im trying to find out if theres any thing similar to codeigniter as there is in Zend where I can append files to a header area like CSS or Footer area like javascript. Problem is I can't find anything which means either one doesn't exist and I have to make one (which not sure how to tackle that exactly), or I am searching for the wrong thing. Or I dunno. Anyone here know something?

Comment: Codeigniter doesn't explicitly support templates.
But look up `codeigniter template` you'll find a bunch of stuff.

Comment: I normally have a view called template, every controller loads that view. And in the `$data` array I pass it a view and other information.

Comment: Nope. However, I know this as an issue when u r working with cross framework apps. Ideally, using Zend libs on CI has helped me but never tried for headlink... You might want to consider an alternative, I tried and researched, wasted my time.

Comment: I've built for the most part what I consider to be a decent templating method in ci to date but as of late I have gotten into Zend with my job and I am liking it's features was ultimately hoping to find a similar method in ci that workes better than the method I have implemented which is in my header and footer files I have my global CSS an js then through a a data array in the controllers I pass unique files if needed to the views

Comment: That said I have many sites built up of which I don't want to rebuild with Zend so I figure if I go I'm and ever do serious work on them I may do some optimizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I am usually using in my CI projects...

1. application/views/v_header.php

   ```
       <head>
               <title><?php print $this->config->item('sitename'); if(isset($title)) echo ' - '.$title; ?></title>
               <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
               <meta name="generator" content="xxxxxx" />
               <meta name="author" content="Matteo Mattei - www.matteomattei.com"/>
               <meta name="description" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
               <meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW"/>
               <meta name="keywords" content="xxxxx, xxxxx, xxxxx"/>
               <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/favicon.ico" />
               <?php
               if(isset($style))
               {
                       if(is_array($style))
                       {
                               foreach($style as $s)
                                       echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.base_url().'css/'.$s.'" type="text/css" media="screen" />';
                       }
                       else
                               echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.base_url().'css/'.$style.'" type="text/css" media="screen" />';
               }
               ?>
               <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
               <?php
               if(isset($jquery) && $jquery===TRUE)
                       echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.base_url().'js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>';
               echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
               echo 'var base_url="'.base_url().'";';
               if(isset($js_variables))
               {
                       foreach($js_variables as $k=>$v)
                       {
                               echo 'var '.$k.'="'.$v.'";';
                       }
               }
               echo '</script>';
               if(isset($js))
               {
                       if(is_array($js))
                       {
                               foreach($js as $j)
                                       echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.base_url().'js/'.$j.'"></script>';
                       }
                       else
                               echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.base_url().'js/'.$js.'"></script>';
               }
               ?>
       </head>
       <body>
   ```
2. In each controllwer function I can specify custom CSS files or JS files:

   ```
   public function myfunc()
   {
           $data['jquery'] = TRUE;
           $data['js'] = array(
                   'jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js',
                   'my_special.js',
                   'another_special.js',
           );
           $data['style'] = array(
                   'ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css',
                   'my_custom.css',
           );

           $this->load->view('v_header',$data);
           $this->load->view('v_menu',$data);
           $this->load->view('v_dashboard',$data);
           $this->load->view('v_footer',$data);
   }
   ```